# Can´t stick my footer to the bottom

Tags: css, footer

I´m doing a test website and I´m trying to stick properly the footer at the bottom of the website but I can´t do it.

The footer is at the bottom but it doesn´t go down with the content of the website. For example, if you click on "Express Request Form" button, you can check what happens.

I appreciate a lot if anyone can help me, please.

You can check the website in link below:

http://www.flexacademy.co/test/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `main-wrapper-block` ends, put a div `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

This happen because when you `float` child elements, they does not behave like normal block elements, thus parent did not get proper height. Whenewer you use `float` use `clear:both` to prevent this problem. You page got previous height cause you have given min-height to divs.

Answer (score 2):

Use a clearfix or give your footer a `clear: both` should solve your problems, because you use floats.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past and it does exactly what you are trying to do. http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Very easy to implement as well. If this doesn't suit your needs, let me know and I will find something that will. :)

[Here is how to implement it.](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in layout:

**Html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-2">
        <p>header and content of the page</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper{min-height:100%;}
.wrapper-2 {
    padding-bottom:70px; /* footer height + distance between footer and content */
}
#footer{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:-50px; /* footer height */
}
```

Compare your code and my example and so changes

Answer (score 1):

Use this trick, it works for such dynamic height changes in page:
HTML:

```
<div id="footer">foo</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function () {
    positionFooter();
});

function positionFooter() {

    var docHeight = $(document.body).height() - $("#sticky-footer-push").height();
    if (docHeight < $(window).height()) {
        var diff = $(window).height() - docHeight;
        if (!$("#sticky-footer-push").length > 0) {
            $("#footer").before('<div id="sticky-footer-push"></div>');
        }
        $("#sticky-footer-push").height(diff);

    }
}
positionFooter();
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/ag5Rx/1/

You can find original article [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/).